# What is the name of this naming convention? "this-is-an-identifier"

Tags: naming-conventions

Parts of a composed name are separated by "-" and all the letter are lower case. I know that *thisIsAIdentifier* is **camel case**, but don't the name of this one ;)

Comment: There probably isn't a name, but it's common in Lisp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This-is-a-hyphenated-identifier